# LINQ won't let me create a custom attribute (like Id + Name)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

What I'm trying to do is to create a custom type, with a custom attribute that will store both  Id and Name from a record. (Something like "223 - Robert Smith"). This is what I'm doing:

```
return (from c in db.Credores
        where c.Status == true
        select new CredorCompleto
        {
            Id = c.Id,
            Nome = c.Nome,
            NomeCompleto = c.Id + c.Nome,
            CNPJ = c.CNPJ
        }).ToList();
```

**Update:** Definition for 'CredorCompleto'

```
public class CredorCompleto
{
    public string NomeCompleto { get; set; }
    public string CNPJ { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

This is what I'm getting:

> *Unable to cast the type `System.Int32` to type `System.Object`. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.*

Comment: Can you post the definition of the class `CredorCompleto`?

Comment: did you try casting to string first? like, `(c.Id + c.Nome).ToString()`

Comment: I'm surprised that there's so many answers assuming that `Id` must be an integer and `Nome` a string (which seems indeed quite likely), and that this must be the cause of this problem. Why answer the question when we *don't know* the actual definition for `CredorCompleto`, which would be quite important to know in order to reasonably answer this question? -- Now we have 6 answers all basically stating the same thing, and it *might* even be wrong.

Comment: @stakx : You are right. In **this** case, I am sure that NomeCompleto (Full Name) cannot be anything else than a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your comment on @Moon's answer provides an important clue:

> *"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method `System.String Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object)` method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."*

The problem *might be* that `db.Credores` is an `IQueryable`, and not just an `IEnumerable`. So when your LINQ to SQL provider tries to analyse your original query, it comes upon a bit that it does not recognise, and does not know how to translate to a SQL query.

I suppose the LINQ to SQL provider has problems converting your concatenation `c.Id + c.Nome` into a valid SQL statement, possibly because the former is an `int` and the latter a `string`.

What's for sure is that it definitely doesn't know how to transform a call to `string.Format()` to SQL (which is not surprising, since SQL doesn't have that function).

So you could try to execute the SQL query before you perform .NET-specific logic on it. Try this:

```
return db
       .Credores
       .Where(c => c.Status == true)
       .AsEnumerable() // <-- this should trigger the execution of the SQL query
       .ToList()       // <-- and if it does not, then this certainly will
       .Select(c => new CredorCompleto
                    {
                        …
                    })
       .ToList();
```

The call to `.AsEnumerable()` — and a call to `.ToList()` is probably required also, IIRC — will trigger the execution of the SQL query. Everything after that operates on an in-memory `IEnumerable`, not on a `IQueryable`. This means that after the `.ToList()`, LINQ will do no more smart code analysis, or attempt to transform the remaining operators to SQL.

Comment: +1 for being the only answer to understand the actual problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `.ToString()` of `c.Id` and `c.Nome` returns proper value, you can do this:

```
return (from c in db.Credores
        where c.Status == true
        select c).AsEnumerable()
        .select(x => new CredorCompleto()
        {
            Id = c.Id.ToString(),
            Nome = c.Nome,
            NomeCompleto = string.Format("{0} - {1}", c.Id, c.Nome),
            CNPJ = c.CNPJ
        }).ToList();
```

As suggested by `Victor`, "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method `System.String Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object)`"

For this reason, use `AsEnumerable()`to force evaluation of that part with Linq to Objects.

Comment: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: +1 for being the first answer (IIRC) to have recognised the error's cause (last sentence).

Answer (score -1):

Your trying to concatenate an int and a string.  Try...

```
NomeCompleto = c.Id.ToString() + " - " + c.Nome,
```

Comment: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Answer (score -2):

You asked

> Something like "223 - Robert Smith").

Use this

```
return (from c in db.Credores
                        where c.Status == true
                        select new CredorCompleto
                        {
                            Id = c.Id,
                            Nome = c.Nome,
                            NomeCompleto = c.Id + " - " + c.Nome,
                            CNPJ = c.CNPJ
                        }).ToList();
```

**EDIT:** After seeing your class structure I guess your error is some where else which is not given in question.

Comment: How does this, apart from formatting `NomeCompleto` differently, fix the type conversion exception?

Comment: @stakx:  This would return a string.

Comment: And how do you know that `NomeCompleto` has type `string`? It seems likely, but you're guessing. After all, the error message says that an `int` cannot be converted to an `object`. (Note: it does not say `string`!)

Comment: @stakx: Now can you see why I did that. Now please remove your downvote.

Comment: I still don't see how it is *supposed to* fix the problem. Even if your proposed solution won't work, you should at least *explain* it, so that the OP has a chance of recognising his mistake, instead of just copy & paste-ing your answer and forgetting all about it.

Answer (score -2):

try

```
return (from c in db.Credores
    where c.Status == true
    select new CredorCompleto
    {
        Id = c.Id,
        Nome = c.Nome,
        DescricaoCompleta = c.Id+"-"+c.Nome,
        CNPJ = c.CNPJ
    }).ToList();
```